# 80's fantasy story about two people and a gigantic ant

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, magic

Looking for an 80's fantasy story about two people and their human-sized ant companion/friend.

The people eventually become a couple and are returned to their own world to forget about one another, but to meet.  The ant retires to sleep off the effort of the adventure.

Comment: Is this a book? Short story? Film? Animation?

Comment: This was a short novel.